# Does facebook Send dialog have a mobile version?

Tags: facebook, mobile, dialog, send

If I replace `www` with `m` in the following URL or append `&display=touch` then facebook returns error:

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/send?app_id=123050457758183&
name=People%20Argue%20Just%20to%20Win&
link=http://www.nytimes.com/2011/06/15/arts/people-argue-just-to-win-scholars-assert.html&
redirect_uri=http://www.example.com/response
```

An error occurred with Cool Social App. Please try again later.

Is there any reason send dialog is not supported on mobile devices?

Answer (score 1):

As the [Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/send/) specifies and also this [ticket](http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/269037719820288/?browse=search_4ef41e030097f0863967094) shows, the Send Dialog is not yet supported on Mobile devices!

Comment: if this is the case, how do we correctly identify whether the current device is supported? I don't want to sniff the user agent!